# Watch kit App : Terminated due to memory error

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

Hi I am developing an app in which I require to chache 50 images (size of all images is 2.5 mb) ,It is chaching the images but also increases the memory by 10 mb in Apple Watch App due to which app crashes .

Xcode gives error in xCode “Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory error”

The code i am using is below :

```
 for (var i : Int  = 1; i<26; i++) {

            let filenameHuman = NSString(format: "human_%d", i )
            let filenameZombie = NSString(format: "zombie_%d", i )

            var imageHuman : UIImage! =  UIImage(named: filenameHuman as String)
            var imageZombie : UIImage! =  UIImage(named: filenameZombie as String)

            WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().addCachedImage(imageZombie, name: filenameZombie as String)

            WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().addCachedImage(imageHuman, name: filenameHuman as String)

        }

        NSLog("Currently cached images: %@",WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().cachedImages)
```

Also the screenshot of Memory allocation and memory leak is :

[image]

Please Help, Thanks in advance .

Comment: This won't solve it but might help https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/QA1894/_index.html

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this. I have the exact same issue. Memory goes up every time WKInterfaceDevice.currentDevice().addCachedImage() is called and is not released until after AwakeWithContext completes.

Comment: @BrettHannah I am using above code after the  AwakeWithContext completes and when i pop back ,, memory is not released  . ?

Answer (score 1):

- Are any of your images actually animations (that would use up more space)?
- Collect the return value of each call to addCachedImage().  False means it could not be added -- you need to check to that and it might give clues as to a particular problem image.
- Before calling anything, try to empty the cache, removeAllCachedImages.  This means you will be clean from previous cache interactions using up the pool of memory.

I think your problem is not a leak, I think your problem is over-retained allocations.  So use the Allocations tool (with retain count tracking) to see how much memory was allocated (VM allocations) and how many entities are holding on to such memory (retain counts).

Answer (score 0):

Inside your loop try to autorelease the memory that is used by the images since you don't want to wait for autorelease to happen later when the method returns.

```
for (var i : Int  = 1; i<26; i++) {
    autoreleasepool {
      /* code to cache images */ 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have done that but it didn't helped a lot , it didn't decrease the memory .

Comment: Interesting.  The next thing I would do is try to identify the line of the code that is the culprit.  Start at the bottom of the loop and comment out each line and run the app.  Do it over until it is able to run.  Your two lines where you create the `UIImage` should be ok because you have the autoreleasepool, but maybe there is something going on with it that I am not seeing.